# How can i fetch the top comments from a youtube video with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, youtube, urllib

How can i fetch the top comment from a youtube video? I tried using the urllib and Beautiful Soup modules but I think I either did something wrong or they're outdated. This is pretty much what i want to do:

```
link = http://www.youtube.com/all_comments?v=krTUf7BpTc0
```

and then be able to return:

```
top_comment = "theTopComment"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just asking, why do you dont want to use the youtube api?

Comment: i couldnt get it working before but i guess thats a good point maybe the API is my best option, ill update my question